# Anime Movie with a floating island and robots

Tags: castle-in-the-sky

When I was younger (2003) I rented a movie which I believe to be an anime, though I do believe it was older.

## The details I remember:

(Space Pirates aren't actually in space, they are just named that for convenience, they just fly about in airships)

- **In the beginning** of the movie, there was a boy, who happened to come across, or see a girl falling from the sky, but she never hit the ground, she was floating. (They were young, by appearance, I would say between the ages of 7 and 14)
- I remember a scene rather vividly, where the girl (from above) was climbing on the outside of an airship, trying to escape what I shall call *Space Pirates* as to not let them gain an amulet (not sure on whether it was an amulet or something else entirely, I just know she had it, the *space pirates* wanted it).
- I remember the two of them (Boy and girl, from first point), found their way, somehow onto an island which had a giant tree on it, with a lot of robots which had the ability to fly, it was an old looking place with moss and other overgrowth about.
- The girls amulet, (or other item), had some sort of ability here, and was special to the island.
  I'm note sure, though it may have been that the amulet woke the robots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [Laputa: Castle in the Sky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_in_the_Sky).  The story starts off with a girl on a airship that's attacked by "sky" pirates. She manage to escape both the pirates and the people who held her captive on the airship by falling out of it. The girl's amulet saves her, causing her to float to safely to ground where a young boy find her.

Ultimately they end up on the floating island Laputa, which is old, overgrown, has a giant tree and is populated by giant robots. I believe the robots can fly.

[image: Disney re-release cover]

Comment: I just searched on youtube the title, as I came across a video which confirmed your answer. Thankyou so much.